# Converting PDF to PCL via Ghostscript only without colour?

Tags: pdf, colors, ghostscript, printer-control-language

We are trying to convert some PDF files into PCL files using Ghostscript.
The commandline we're using:

```
gswin32c -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pxlcolor \
 -f ..\examples\pu.pdf -sOutputFile=..\examples\pu.pcl
```

This generates a black&white PCL file.

Please help, what's wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a (link to a) sample file?

Comment: this works with every pdf file ;-))

Comment: I'm sorry to break the bad news for you: On *my* system (Mac OS X) with Ghostscript v9.06, the output of your command gives me a perfectly colored PCL file. Had you given a (link to a) sample color PDF file of yours, I would have converted that one to proof it to you... (or debugged the reason why it wouldn't show colors in PCL).

Comment: ok, that's what i expected. I don't believe that it works wrong. But when every converted pdf doesn't print colored, there should be a systematic mistake on my side. Could it be, that the printer (lexmark x736de) doesn't "understand" the generated pcl?

Comment: After generating the PCL, how exactly are you printing to your Lexmark? Are you sure that the Lexmark isn't set to convert all color to grayscale? (The PCL's first line should read `<esc>%-12345X@PJL SET RENDERMODE=COLOR` -- this is a PJL command to set the printer to print color, but most printers can be set up to ignore this and instead enforce grayscale printing).